# how to update the name of multiple objects to lowercase in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i need to update the all user who have the rol user and change the nickName to lowercase,  i try with this code

```js
const users = await userModel.updateMany({ rol:'user' },
    { 
      $set:{
        nickName: { 
          $toLower : "$nickName"
        }
      }
    });
```

but is not working

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please describe in what way your approach is not working. I went ahead and copied your example into [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gqJAtgJvPab) and saw that your current approach resulted in the document being modified to include this field:

```
    "nickName": {
      "$toLower": "$nickName"
    }
```

The problem here is that you are attempting to use the (aggregation) `$set` stage in your update (so that you can reference the existing `$nickName` field), but the update is using the `$set` (non-aggregation) modifier.  If you wrap your second argument in square brackets (telling the database that you want to use an aggregation) then it should do what you want:

```
db.collection.update({
  rol: "user"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      nickName: {
        $toLower: "$nickName"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IumvhQ5eLCM)